# Responsive GridView fullScreen flutter

Tags: flutter, gridview, flutter-layout

I would like to have my gridview to take the whole screen, but i can't find a way to do this.
I already check multiple blog like :
https://medium.com/nusanet/flutter-gridview-bad48c1f216c

But this doesn't seem to work in my case.
Even when i'm using MediaQuery Data to get the screen width and height to adapt the childAspectRation.

**Here my gridview :**

```
GridView.count(
                childAspectRatio: (widthScreen / heightScreen),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                crossAxisSpacing: 15,
                mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                children: <Widget>[
                  CardItem(
                    imageUrl: 'assets/images/apprendreajouer.jpg',
                    title: 'Apprendre à jouer',
                    function: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        CupertinoPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => ListLevelsPage(
                            pageTitle: "Cours",
                            pageKey: 1,
                            context: context,
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                  CardItem(
                    imageUrl: 'assets/images/exercices.jpeg',
                    title: 'Exercice',
                    function: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        CupertinoPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => ListLevelsPage(
                            pageTitle: "Exercices",
                            pageKey: 2,
                            context: context,
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                  CardItem(
                    imageUrl: 'assets/images/partition.jpg',
                    title: 'Partition',
                    function: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        CupertinoPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => ListLevelsPage(
                            pageTitle: "Partition",
                            pageKey: 3,
                            context: context,
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                  CardItem(
                    imageUrl: 'assets/images/dictionnaire.jpeg',
                    title: 'Mon dictionnaire',
                    function: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        CupertinoPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => ListLevelsPage(
                            pageTitle: "Dictionnaire d'accords",
                            pageKey: 4,
                            context: context,
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                  CardItem(
                    imageUrl: 'assets/images/examen.jpeg',
                    title: 'Examen',
                  ),
                  CardItem(
                    imageUrl: 'assets/images/apropos.jpg',
                    title: 'A propos',
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

**Here below an image of what i want :**

[image]

**Update of what i get using @Thierry source code :**

[image]
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some discrepancies in your code.

You cannot define:

- 6 `children` for your `GridView`
- `childAspectRatio` of `widthScreen / heightScreen`
- `crossAxisCount: 2`

You can keep your `childAspectRatio` and `crossAxisCount` if you reduce the number of `children` to 4.

If you want 6 `children` on 3 `Rows`, then change the `childAspectRatio` to `MediaQuery.of(context).size.aspectRatio * 3 / 2`.

[image]

If you want 6 `children` on 2 `Rows`, then increase `crossAxisCount` to 3, and change the `childAspectRatio` to `MediaQuery.of(context).size.aspectRatio * 2 / 3`.

*Note: You can continue like that. if you want m `Rows` of n `children`, the `childAspectRatio` should be `m/n`.*

### Full source code (6 `children` on 3 `Rows`)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('GridView Demo')),
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) => GridView.count(
          childAspectRatio: constraints.biggest.aspectRatio * 3 / 2,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          children: List.generate(
            6,
            (index) => Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
              child: CardItem(
                imageUrl: 'assets/images/abstract$index.jpg',
                title: 'Abstract $index',
              ),
            ),
          ).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CardItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imageUrl;
  final String title;
  final VoidCallback function;

  const CardItem({Key key, this.imageUrl, this.title, this.function})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: function,
      child: Card(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage(imageUrl),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            ),
          ),
          child: Text(title),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not exactly what i want.. what i want is crossAxisCount to 2 with 6 children taking the whole screen. I updated my post with some images.

Comment: I tried your source code but it doesn't perfectly fit the screen, i think it's better that i build my own gridview

Comment: You probably have something else on your screen, like an `AppBar`? You should then get your `width` and `height` from a `LayoutBuilder` Widget. Check my last update.

Comment: Yes i had an AppBar, thank you !  It fits perfectly now.